# Echo in makefile and backlash escapes

Tags: newline, echo

When a variable contains the output of a commande, printing this variable with echo suppresses the new lines.
Escaping the backslashes with `echo -e` does not work. Setting the `SHELL` variable does not help either.

Example :

```
$ cat log1.txt 
terminated
terminator

$ gmake
terminated terminator
```

With the following makefile :

```
all:
    @ab=`cat log1.txt`;\
    echo -e $$ab
```

Makefile version : *GNU Make 3.82*

Comment: That's a shell issue. It has nothing to do with `make`.

Comment: What do you want to do with this variable besides `echo` it?

Comment: Just displaying it, for debugging purposes. How come `echo -e` works in a shell script and not with `make` then ?

Comment: I don't get the newline using `echo -e` either in a shell script or from the command line. And if you're just displaying it, instead of "@ab=`cat log1.txt`; echo -e $$ab", why not just "@cat log1.txt"?

Comment: You're right, I cannot get it to work in a shell (again).

The idea is to display the result of an execution only when it has failed (unit tests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitively a shell issue. The same code in a shell script does not work either.